# Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelector' in IE 10

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer

I encounter a problem with IE 10 regarding its support. The website is very good to use in other browser except IE.. I also tried using IE 11 and still it didn't work.

I used angularJS and IE could not recognize `querySelector`..

Can anyone have an idea how to solve this one? Please help me..

The version of of my AngularJS is v1.2.22

I attached my error message

[image]
[image]

Thank you so much for helping me..

**UPDATE**

Through the help of `Syed Ali Taqi` I already passed that error by **Deleting all history, and cookies and resetting the settings** but i got a new problem and it is like this

`[$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest`

[image]

I wonder why the IE error that part but not in other browser like Chrome and firefox.. I am very sensitive in compatibility of site to all browser because we cannot dictate the user what browser to use..

Please anyone can help me

Comment: Have you set `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Yes its already set to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and when i change my ie to compatibility mode still it break to that error

Comment: I guess you should try **Without** compatibility mode.

Comment: the default of my IE browser is not in compatibility mode but still it didn't work..

Comment: Start by figuring out what the object actually is and what it is supposed to be.

Comment: Try adding this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` line in your `<head></head>`

Comment: Actually the error pointed to angularJS and i cant change that in angularJS

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi yes i already tried that one..

Comment: Can you post the `HTML` code line of query selector?

Comment: Actually the queryselector is from angularJS and it's a lot of code to post..its a framework i used for my client side..

Comment: After a bit of Googling I found that some people resolved this issue by **Deleting all History, Clearing cookies and Resetting the IE settings**

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082715/angular-js-element-has-no-method-queryselector) might be helpful.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi your suggestion resetting the ie settings ng deleting all history works but I got another problem.. `[$rootScope:inprog]` this error showed in my console

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733422/angularjs-rootscopeinprog-inprogress-error)
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128220/angularjs-scope-apply-gives-this-error-error-rootscopeinprog), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858841/getting-angularjs-error-rootscopeinprog-digest-already-in-progress-witho)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

> - Delete all History
> - Clear Cookies
> - Reset IE settings

Comment: yes that solved my problem please help me to my other problem i tried the link you give me but it pointed to my angularJS..

Comment: Yes the problem now is in your AngularJS code. Have you tried it in other browsers and did it work fine?

Comment: yes it work fine with the other browser except IE.. The one i troubleshoot earlier is the IE..

Comment: I haven't worked with AngularJS much. But I'm working on your problem, will update you ASAP.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I really appreciate your help..I'm still testing which angularJS version is compatible with IE.. I hope it will give me a positive result..

Comment: Which version of AngularJS are you using right now? Is it 1.2.x or greater?

Comment: yes i used 1.2.22 version.. i reading now the link you give to me..i will try if it can solve my problem..thanks

Comment: no probelm :) also give [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896793/angularjs-directive-with-http-requests-inprog-error) a look. Might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot..ok i will read that one and i will try it out and thanks for the help.. :) The one like you makes the stackoverflow helpful to us.. :)

Comment: I currently reading the one you give and trying to fix the error thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I think it's something else that is fails. http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector according to that the support should be there in IE10.

Make sure the IE is not using any compatability mode to view your site.
Goto Settings > compatatibilty mode > make sure display intranet sites in compatability mode is NOT checked.

Comment: I tried it.. the error didnt show but in my inspect element console it showed that `SCRIPT5: Access is denied.` which pointed to `gsd.html, line 1 character 1` which that html file is not coming from my project

Answer (score 0):

please see the [IE9 equivalent of querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171247/ie9-equivalent-of-queryselectorall) and check the compatibility mode of your IE browser also.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by IE's compatibility mode. You can go under Compatibility View Settings and see if your sites domain is listed.

Answer (score 0):

IE Developer Tools [F12] was useful for me in diagnosing this (IE11):

- the toolbar on dev tools has a dropdown that lets you select IE compatibility version

  - [image: toolbar screenshot]
- set the desired version using the dropdown on the toolbar, then refresh the page
- in my case the error went away when using version 8 or greater

To fix the issue, I ended up adding a `meta` tag as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771584/10239655).  (I actually added it via the web.config as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16977991/10239655)).