# Couldn't override console.log in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, console.log

Here's my code to over-ride console.log(), and works well in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc.

```
var _log = console.log.bind(console); 
window.console.log = function (data)
{
    _log.call(this,data);
    //do something
}
```

But, latest version of Microsoft Edge throws me an error.

> SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action

(at line 1 - `var _log = console.log.bind(console);` to be specific)

How can I make it work on Edge? Why this doesn't work?

Comment: Someone answered this question, but it disappeared now. O.O

Comment: It wasn't an answer.  It was a points scrub copying and pasting something completely incorrect, just because it was the same error message.  They deleted it when it was downvoted.

Comment: Engineer from the Edge team; [works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/etQgK.png).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Sampson. I tried resetting all Edge settings after seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25566286/5132413), it worked.

Comment: @unix_root Happy to hear that it's working. Probably best to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When surfing SO about this, saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25566286/5132413) answer and cleared all my Edge settings and data. It worked.